# C++ - detect is first base class at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I'd like to detect that `class Base` is the **first** base of `class Deriv`. That is, they have the same pointer.

The example below doesn't work. I tried a few more things, wrapping casts in functions and unions, and got nowhere.

With a union it works only if all the types are literal - default destructable etc, which my classes are not.

Is there a way to do it? ideally in C++14?

```
template <class Base, class Deriv, bool IsBase = std::is_base_of<Base, Deriv>::value>
struct is_first_base_of {
    static constexpr bool value = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(1) == static_cast<Base*>(reinterpret_cast<Deriv*>(1)); // this doesn't work
};
template <class Base, class Deriv>
struct is_first_base_of<Base, Deriv, false> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

struct A1 { int a1; }
struct A2 { int a2; }
struct B : A1, A2 { int b; }
static_assert(is_first_base_of<A1, B>::value == true, "");
static_assert(is_first_base_of<A2, B>::value == false, "");
```

**UPDATE**

That's the code I use now following @user17732522's idea of static_cast-ing to `void*`. It works on g++ 5.5, but not on 10.3:

```
template <class Base, class Deriv, bool IsBase = std::is_base_of<Base, Deriv>::value>
struct is_first_base_of {
    static constexpr const Deriv* p0 = nullptr;
    static constexpr const Deriv* p1 = &(p0[123]); // must use non-null!
    static constexpr const void*  base()  { return static_cast<const void*>(static_cast<const Base*>(p1)); }
    static constexpr const void*  deriv() { return static_cast<const void*>(p1); }
    static constexpr bool         value = base() == deriv();
};
template <class Base, class Deriv>
struct is_first_base_of<Base, Deriv, false> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

Comment: In the example you are giving `B` is not standard-layout. Therefore there is no guarantee that the first base will share the address of the `B` object and `reinterpret_cast`ing between them (and using the resulting pointer) causes undefined behavior. Also, what do you expect `reinterpret_cast<Base*>(1)` etc. to do?

Comment: Given what I said above, what you really might be looking for is [`std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of), which as mentioned above will however be `false` in both of your test cases.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for the comments. I thought that it's well defined in practice. Can you please give an example of UB?

Comment: Undefined behavior according to the standard. ABI specifications such as the Itanium C++ ABI will typically specify that the first base class of a non-polymorphic type will share the same address even if not standard-layout, I think. But that alone is not enough to allow `reinterpret_cast` per standard either (at least since C++17). I do not think however that any compiler currently optimizes based on that, so it likely works in practice with these ABIs.

Comment: A classical case of "the language gets in the way" :|

Comment: For the question itself: I think, except for aggregate classes, there is no general way to detect whether a base is first. If you want to test instead whether the base has the same address, then `static_cast<void*>(static_cast<Base*>(x)) == static_cast<void*>(x)` should be fine and should also work in constant expression evaluation. However you need to create a `x` of type `Deriv` first, limiting the approach. Something like `reinterpret_cast<Deriv*>(/*number*/)` has undefined behavior. Because of empty base class optimization a second base may satisfy this test as well. And see notes above.

Comment: @user17732522 - I didn't think of casting to `void*` - this did the trick, thanks!
I don't care if it's really the first base. First, for me, means deriv and base have the same pointer so I can cast to base* safely and not go through something like boost polymorphic cast.
Do you want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: is `boost::polymorphic_cast` not simply a `static_cast`/`dynamic_cast` dependent on debug/release configuration? Why do you compare it with a `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: *If* you have a `Base*` *and if* you know that it points to a `Derived` *and if* you know that `Base` is the first or zero-offset base class of `Derived`, it is *still* not enough to know that you can reinterpret-cast `Base*` to `Derived*`, because there may be more than one `Base` that Derived` derives from.

Comment: @user17732522 - `boost::polymorphic_cast` is like a virtual call. My impl is something like this, but with a bit more wrapping - `auto funcs[sizeof...(Ts)] = { [&]{ return static_cast<Base*>(interpret_cast<Ts*>(storage_)) }... };
return (funcs[vt_])();`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. - You are right, of course, but that's a complex case I'm not really interested in, in this context. This variant class I wrote is specific to where I work. It's not trying to kosher at the same level as std stuff. Sometimes latency is more important than other things :)

Comment: @BitWhistler `polymorphic_cast` is just a `dynamic_cast` and `polymorphic_downcast` is just a `static_cast` with runtime debug assertion that the cast isn't invalid. See https://github.com/boostorg/conversion/blob/master/include/boost/polymorphic_cast.hpp. In the line you are showing in the comment there doesn't seem to be anything depending on the relative address between base and derived at all. The `reinterpret_cast` (which is conceptually completely different than a `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`) seems to be applied to get a pointer to the _derived_ class.

Comment: @BitWhistler (That is technically still missing `std::launder` after the `reinterpret_cast` though.)

Comment: The added code in your question shouldn't compile at least if you try to instantiate the template. `p0[123]` has undefined behavior, so it makes the program ill-formed since you are forcing it in a constant expression context. Even if that wasn't the case, it is still UB and in particular it violates alignment requirements of your classes, which the compiler is likely to optimize based on. As I mentioned, to do make this work, especially at compile-time, you must actually create a derived object. If you can't because you don't know the constructors, then this approach can't be used.

Comment: @user17732522
Maybe I'll use `std::launder` in the function itself, when I switch from C++14 to C++17...
But here, in the same pointer detection code, after the udpate, it's all static cast :) Thanks

Comment: That's actually true :( It compiles great with an old compiler but not with a new one :((( now the language really gets in the way. I'll just reinterpret_cast w/o checking

Comment: @BitWhistler To be honest, I still don't follow where you are using which cast and for what purpose exactly. A `static_cast` between class pointers is always fine as long as you make sure that in a downcast the object is actually of the derived type. Address differences are irrelevant. And `reinterpret_cast` from the storage array is also always allowed as long as the cast is to the same most-derived type that was `new`ed at that address. `reinterpret_cast`ing directly to a base class pointer from the storage is the only problematic part, but also completely avoidable with an indirect call.

Comment: I'm `reinterpret_cast`-ing directly to a base class pointer from the storage to _avoid_ an indirect call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aggregate classes you can probably use the aggregate initialization mechanism and conversion operator templates to detect the first base's type.

Except for this class, I don't think it is generally possible to detect the first base class.

---

If you want to test instead whether the base has the same address, then `static_cast<void*>(static_cast<Base*>(x)) == static_cast<void*>(x)` should be fine and should also work in constant expression evaluation. It will fail to compile if `Base` is an ambiguous or inaccessible base of `Deriv`.

However you need to create a `x` of type `Deriv` first, limiting the approach. Something like `reinterpret_cast<Deriv*>(/*number*/)` to create such an object, as you are attempting in your question, has undefined behavior when passed to the `static_cast<Base*>`, even if `number` is `0`. `std::declval` is also not possible since this is an evaluated context. Therefore `Deriv` must have some constructor that is known to be usable (in the constant expression).

This is not the same as finding the first base though. The standard specifies memory layout requirements only for standard-layout types, which the type in your question is not.

Even with usual ABI specifications providing for class layout in all cases, this is not the same as finding the first base. Because of empty base class optimization a second base may satisfy this test as well.

---

Although the latter test verifies that the address of the base class subobject is equal to that of the derived object, the standard does not allow simply `reinterpret_cast`ing between the two types if the class is not standard-layout, at least since C++17 (and maybe earlier as well). The requirement for that is stricter and called [*pointer-interconvertibility*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#pointer-interconvertible). This stricter property can be tested for with [`std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of).

Casting from derived-to-base, assuming the addresses are equal, is still possible by applying [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) after `reinterpret_cast`. However, the reverse is not allowed by the `std::launder` precondition.

I am not sure why the `std::launder` reachability precondition is that way in this case, since it is possible to obtain a pointer to the derived class via `static_cast` anyway, but the condition doesn't take that into account. In the case of members rather than bases, the condition allows a compiler to assume that other class subobjects cannot be reached through a pointer to such a member, assuming pointer-interconvertibility does not apply.

Comment: my use case is a variant class, so I'm not reinterpret_cast-ing derived to base, but char[N] to T, if all Ts have a T base with the same pointer. If they don't have the same pointer as the base, I'm forced to use static_cast on the currently contained type, and this is like a virtual call, like boost::polymorphic_cast

Comment: @BitWhistler In that case the cast to the `T` base is allowed if `std::launder`ed and you verified the address equality. You can then cast from the base to the derived via `static_cast` but not generally `reinterpret_cast`. I am not sure how useful that is though.

Comment: Added `is_first_base_of<Base, Deriv>` for the benefit of whoever is looking here